# How can you unhold (remove a hold on) a package?

Tags: apt

I used synaptic to lock the version of `pidgin-data` - how can I change the status from `hold` back to normal, so that it gets upgraded properly?

The [PinningHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) says that doing an `apt-get install packagename` should remove the `hold`, but running `dpkg -l | grep ^h` still shows it as held:

```
hi  pidgin-data                                                 1:2.10.6-0ubuntu1+pidgin1.12.04                            multi-protocol instant messaging client - data files
```

How can I properly undo the `hold` status?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can use `sudo apt-mark unhold package_name`. The package is unheld and it returns a confirmation: `Canceled hold on package_name.`.

To unhold all held packages you can use `sudo apt-mark unhold $(apt-mark showhold)`.

Comment: Your `sudo` problem is probably because you wrote just `sudo echo "package_name install"|dpkg --set-selections`. This sudoes the `echo` but not the following pipe, hence the access error. Try this instead: `sudo -E -- sh -c 'echo "package_name install"|dpkg --set-selections'`. This sudoes a sub-shell whose command line is `echo "package_name install"|dpkg --set-selections`.

Comment: My answer was somewhat related to the unedited version of the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/164589/82517) here below which previously included exactly the command I referenced.

However the question specifically uses `apt-get` as an example and that is why I answered using `apt-mark` which is included in the [apt](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/apt) package.

It is however very helpful to know exactly why the dpkg commands were not working.

Comment: @DrA7 package_name was already not hold. What should I do now?

Comment: I had the same problem as @Dr.jacky, but when I try to `apt upgrade` it still tells me the same packages are being kept back!

Answer (score 19):

To unhold all held packages, use this command:

```
apt-mark unhold $(apt-mark showhold)
```

Answer (score 15):

The correct way to remove the hold should be:

```
echo "package_name install"|sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Answer (score 3):

Unhold a single package named $package_name:

```
echo $package_name install | dpkg --set-selections
```

Unhold all packages that are currently held:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold | awk '{ print $1, "install" }' | dpkg --set-selections
```

Answer (score 3):

You can unhold all APT packages with:

```
apt-mark showhold | awk '{ print $1, "install" }' | dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Another way is ```apt-mark showhold | xargs sudo apt-mark unhold```.

Answer (score 1):

Run `echo pidgin-data install | dpkg --set-selections` (replace `pidgin-data` with the held package name) - this will change the package status to `install` rather than `hold`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer worked for me, as the packages simply could not be upgraded because of unmet dependencies.

I had to remove some packages. I've followed [this blog post instructions](https://chrisdown.name/2014/02/10/finding-out-why-package-was-held-back-with-apt.html) to figure out which one causes problems:

```bash
apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
```