# Firefox stuck on old version and problems with held packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, firefox, held-packages

I did a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2 two months ago and I noticed recently that firefox was stuck at version 36. I uninstalled it and then the system showed version 35 as the latest. The same applies for some other packages like compiz-plugins which I cannot install because it is stuck on an older version and conflicts with other compiz packages. The system complained many times about held packages before that. I tried fixing broken dependencies but no luck.

What can I do?

Comment: What error messages are given when you try `sudo apt-get install firefox`?

Comment: i don't get an error, the firefox version i get is old(35 instead of 37). This is not the case for my other installation of ubuntu that i have on my laptop which is basically the same as my desktop, i normally get version 37 there. My problem is that i can't get the latest version for some packages from the ubuntu repository, which does not happen on my other installation of ubuntu. (no ppa involved)

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update` show any errors or suspicious output? What do you have in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: sudo apt-get update works normally.  sources.list contains the ubuntu repositories and they seem to be all enabled

Comment: Can you install the latest version of Firefox after the update (and perhaps 'un-holding' it http://askubuntu.com/questions/164587/how-can-you-unhold-remove-a-hold-on-a-package)  - and can you install Firefox from a deb package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/firefox ?

Comment: 1: it says ''firefox was already not hold''. 2: I tried the deb file through gdebi and it says '' Error:Breaks existing package 'hunspell-en-us' that conflict: 'Iceweasel'.But 'firefox_37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb' provides it via :'gnome-www-browser,Iceweasel,www-browser'". Then i tried through "dpkg -i" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the server in **Software and Updates**. For some reason the server I was using for the updates was misbehaving.